# Can't read the content of a remote variable which was stored locally

Tags: javascript

here's the scenario: I have a node server running locally (for production purposes) and I get a file from it through the following function:

```
function actualizarMapa()
{   

    $.getScript( "http://localhost/paradas.js" ).done(function( script, textStatus ) {      

        console.log("paradas[0][6] de archivo ");console.log(paradas[0][6]);
        actualizoMarkers(paradas);
    }).fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {

        $( "#aviso" ).html( "<p>Servidor fuera de servicio. Reintente luego</p>" );
        });


};
```

(The content of this file changes periodically in minutes)

The content of paradas.js is an array:

```
var paradas = [['01 - Teatro Solís - Liniers y Reconquista','-34.907822','-56.200436',3,1,'Oficina de Atención Movete',8,20,'1'],['02 - Templo Inglés - Reconquista y Treinta Tres','-34.909481','-56.204361',4,1,'Oficina de Atención Movete',12,20,'1'],['03 - Reconquista y Pérez Castellanos','-34.910782','-56.209106',5,1,'Oficina de Atención Movete',12,20,'1'],['04 - Hospital Maciel - Guaraní y Washington','-34.908863','-56.212181',6,1,'Oficina de Atención Movete',13,16,'1'],['05 - Mercado del Puerto - Piedras y Pérez Castellanos','-34.906021','-56.211327',7,1,'Oficina de Atención Movete',5,20,'1'],['08 - Plaza Matriz - Juan Carlos Gómez y Rincón','-34.906101','-56.203266',8,1,'Oficina de Atención Movete',9,20,'1'],['07 - Terminal Ciudadela Norte - Piedras y Juncal','-34.902901','-56.202896',9,1,'Oficina de Atención Movete',15,20,'1'],['06 - Banco de la República - Zabala y Piedras','-34.905022','-56.208302',10,1,'Oficina de Atención Movete',3,16,'1'],['Oficina de Atención Movete','-34.9067246','-56.2108961',0,-1,'Montevideo',0,0,'1']    ];
```

However the log doesn't display the correct value, paradas[0][6] should be 8 but it shows 11 instead. It seems it gets the value from another "ghost" variable.

The HTML file has the script tag to this file also.

Any ideas how I should do to get it correctly?. I tryed passing the array to the function but it didn't work.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code works correctly in a jsbin which suggests the contents of `paradas` in your running code inst the same as the example pasted in the question.

here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yulavo/1/) showing your `paradas` varaible and a `console.log(paradas[0][6])`

It correctly gives `8` (open dev tools to see the value.)

Try debugging the returned `paradas` values with `console.log(paradas);` does that come out at the right value you've pasted in the question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a caching issue. getScript() should not cache anything by default, but you might have switched caching on somewhere outside the funciton you are showing, e.g. globally for all AJAX requests.

Clear browser cache and try again, you will see whether this is a caching issue indeed.